# why isnt my 3d model like what is should be?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

i am creating a website with react and next js. i want to display a 3d model in my website. i downloaded a file with `glb` format and i saw that [in this website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJNo.jpg)

then i displayed the model in my website by using `@react-three/fiber`, `@react-three/drei` and `three`. but there are a lot of differences between the model i saw in the `babylon sandbox` and my website.

[the view that i saw in babylon sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJNo.jpg)

[the view that i see in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtB71.jpg)

converted codes from the glb file:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export default function Model(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/apple-iphone-13-pro-max.glb')
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
        <group rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.01}>
          <group scale={100}>
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Mic_0.geometry} material={materials.material} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Bezel_0.geometry} material={materials.Bezel} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Body_0.geometry} material={materials.Body} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Wallpaper_0.geometry} material={materials.Wallpaper} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Camera_Glass_0.geometry} material={materials.Camera_Glass} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Lens_0.geometry} material={materials.Lens} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Material_0.geometry} material={materials.Material} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera_Body_0.geometry} material={materials.Body} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera_Glass_0.geometry} material={materials.Glass} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera_Camera_Frame001_0.geometry} material={materials['Camera_Frame.001']} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera_Mic_0.geometry} material={materials.material} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Body001_Screen_Glass_0.geometry} material={materials.Screen_Glass} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Button_Frame_0.geometry} material={materials.Frame} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Circle003_Frame_0.geometry} material={materials.Frame} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Apple_Logo_Logo_0.geometry} material={materials.Logo} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Body_0.geometry} material={materials.Body} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Gray_Glass_0.geometry} material={materials.Gray_Glass} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Flash_0.geometry} material={materials.Flash} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Port_0.geometry} material={materials.Port} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Camera_Frame_0.geometry} material={materials.Camera_Frame} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Camera_Glass_0.geometry} material={materials.Camera_Glass} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Lens_0.geometry} material={materials.Lens} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera001_Black_Glass_0.geometry} material={materials.Black_Glass} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Camera003_Material002_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.002']} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Frame_Frame_0.geometry} material={materials.Frame} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Frame_Frame2_0.geometry} material={materials.Frame2} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Frame_Port_0.geometry} material={materials.Port} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Frame_Antenna_0.geometry} material={materials.Antenna} />
            <mesh geometry={nodes.Frame_Mic_0.geometry} material={materials.material} />
          </group>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/apple-iphone-13-pro-max.glb')
```

the codes of where i display the model:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import Model from "./apple-iphone-13-pro-max";

const ModelDisplayer = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      camera={{ position: [5, 5, 5], fov: 10 }}
      className="w-full h-full bg-orange-500"
    >
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Model position={[0, 0, 0]} />
      </Suspense>
      <ambientLight intensity={7} />
      <directionalLight intensity={3} />
      <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ModelDisplayer;
```

how can i make the model view of my website exactly like the `babylon sandbox`? (i played a lot with `directionalLight` and `directionalLight` but i couldnt make the model of my website exactly like what i saw in `babylon sandbox`). and i dont have experience in using the above packages and canva. thanks for helping.

Comment: Change `fov` to something more human, like `60` and move the camera closer. Now it looks as if you would look at it through a telescope.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski +1 
also try 
 THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping and add some scene.environment 
will give a natural look

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thanks for help. i tried what you said but it made the model a little better and it has some problems yet. for example the sides of the phone are dark and i even cant see the charge port and the speakers. but the back of the pone is now almost like what i saw in `babylon sandbox`. i set the `fov` of `Canvas` to 100 and the `position` to `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]`.

Comment: @Cid-Wings thanks for help. how can i use these? i tested what you said and i logged `THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping` and `scene.environment` but these have default value and i changed the default values and i saw no affect. i think the way that i tried your solution is wrong. can you please write a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into drei [Staging](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#staging)

especially you can look into [Stage](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#stage) and also [Environment](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#environment) components

This will automatically handle proper studio lighting, shadows and more.

**EDIT**

Usage of Stage from drei

```
import { Stage } from "@react-three/drei";
...
...

<Stage>
    <Model />
</Stage>
```

You can add your model component and wrap it in a Stage Component.

You can also add in some props to Stage component such as

- intensity
- environment
- preset
- shadows
  and more.

You can view the documentation for more info [here](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#stage)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @hemanth04 hello. thanks for your answer. can you please write an example for me? so i can understand almost exactly what i should do. it'll be nice if you write an example for me.